# How do I correctly retrieve objects from a database using Django REST api?

Tags: django, rest, filtering

I'm teaching my self how to use the Django REST api but I'm running into a JSONDecodeError. I'm trying to display posts depending on the user that is stored in the session.  I'm storing the user username, password, and id in the session for later use.
The JSONDecodeError is targeting the line with instruction posts = posts_response.json() when I look at the HTML error page

Here's my views.py:

```
posts_path = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/"

def index(request):
   if request.method=='GET':
       post_form = PostForm()
       posts_response = requests.get(posts_path)
       posts = posts_response.json()
       context = {
            'post_form': post_form,
            'post_list': posts,
       }
       return render(request, 'UserLanding/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, "UserLanding/index.html")
```

This is my viewsets:

```
class PostView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.session['id'])
        return query_set

class SubscriberView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Subscriber.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SubscriberSerializer
```

My registered urls:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', viewsets.PostView)
router.register('users', viewsets.SubscriberView)
```

And serializers:

```
class SubscriberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Subscriber
    fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'post_text', 'pub_date', 'user')
```

Please help me spot the problem.  Thanks in advance

EDIT: 
I was able to fix the problem by adding a function to my PostView code like this:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['GET'], url_path=r'(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)')
def find_by_user_id(self, request, user_id):
    user = Subscriber.objects.get(id=user_id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(posts, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

and my request.get() now points to this:

```
posts_response = requests.get(posts_path + str(request.session['id']))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems like you are trying to get request, then send another request to the same server, get response and render HTML. I mean why do you need Viewsets here at all?

Comment: I need to get posts that belong to a certain user

Comment: As far as I know, the viewsets are what determine what data is sent back when you do a requests.get(url).  I may be misunderstanding things though.

Comment: Yes, but also Viewsets has defined methods for create/retrieve/update/delete. But the main thing - they return serialized data and as I see you want to render HTML page instead.

Comment: If you want to get related posts, just use filter. `posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to figure out is: what if another developer was using my API and was trying to retrieve certain information? For example, what if they wanted to retrieve an authenticated user's posts that contained the word "Hello".  They would have to make a requests.get() call right?  I'm trying to focus on using the REST API rather than just retrieving straight from the database, because my viewset is already doing that.

Comment: I'm also passing that related data to the page being rendered.  I'm assuming this is the standard way of doing things.  Retrieve data, pass it to the HTML page for display.

Comment: If I remove the def get_queryset(self) function from the PostView, everything works fine, but no matter what user is logged in it shows all the posts

Comment: It's not logical. REST is used to get serialized data (like json), not HTML. If you want both - make two different functions with two different paths, one will render HTML, another will send serialized response.

Comment: I mean now you can retrieve data from your database directly and put it into your HTML. Instead of this you call another function with `requests` that takes the data, sends it to the first function, that puts response to HTML - it's unnecessary extra-work for you and for your server.

Comment: Please look at my edit and see what you think.  My roommate helped me out with the problem.